# Display a custom field of a content type in template with PHP?

Tags: theming

I'm using Drupal 7.  I have a content type called Widget.  One of the custom fields is field_widget_position.  When I did a `<?php print_r($page); ?>` in the template, I can see the key-value pair of field_widget_position buried deep in the array.  Is there an easier way to get a handle on field_widget_position instead of typing `<?php echo $page['somefield']['somefield2']['somefield3']['etc....']['field_widget_position']; ?>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
$node->field_widget_position['en'][0]['value']
```

Comment: More generically: `$node->field_widget_position[$node->language][0]['value']`

Answer (score 4):

```
$node->field_widget_position['en'][0]['value']
```

This is a bad solution.

The right solution is

```
render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_widget_position'));
```

or

```
render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_widget_position', array('label' => 'hidden')));
```

if you don't want to print a label.

See http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way for more info.